# Thread-safety / reusability / life-span of AmazonDynamoDBClient?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I'm curious what is the thread-safety and reusability is for the primary DynamoDB entry point `AmazonDynamoDBClient` in the Java SDK? I noticed this statement in the JavaDocs for `DynamoDBMapper`:

> "This class is thread-safe and can be shared between threads. It's also very lightweight, so it doesn't need to be."

Since `DynamoDBMapper` takes a reference to `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, does that mean that `AmazonDynamoDBClient` is similar?

I also thought I saw somewhere that it was *encouraged* to keep and share the `AWSCredentials` because it allowed better management of throttling and session? Since the credentials are the primary dependency of `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, this might also support it having a longer life span?

Answer (score 4):

It's completely thread-safe.  I haven't actually looked through the AWS code but we instantiate a single client for our heavily used web-app and have never had any issues.

If the mapper is threadsafe the client *must* be threadsafe